# How to prove that a bijective transformation is NOT continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, transformation

I am having this transformation $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x  & x \in \mathbb R \setminus
 \mathbb Q
\\x+1 & x \in \mathbb Q 
\end{cases}$$

I've already prooved that this transformation is bijective.

---

**How can I proove that the transformation is NOT continous in every point $x \in \mathbb R $**

Comment: Any non-degenerate interval contains both rational and irrational numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to prove that would be to find a sequence of numbers $a_1,a_2\dots$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n) \neq f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\right)$$

To find such a sequence, try to construct it out of rational numbers, but make the limit irrational...

Comment: Also it should be noted you'll need irrational sequences with the limit being rational.

Comment: @DanZimm No, you don't need those if you have a rational sequence with the limit irrational. For example, if $a_n\to\sqrt 2$ and $a_n$ are all rational, then $f(a_n)=a_n+1$, so the left hand side is $\sqrt{2}+1$, while the right hand side is $f(\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Doesn't this just show that at each irrational point the function is discontinuous? I don't see how we get limiting behavior towards rationals from this.

Comment: @DanZimm A function is continuous on $\mathbb R$ $\iff$ it is continuous at every point in $\mathbb R$. The sequence I described proves that t$f$ is not continuous at $\sqrt{2}$, so it is not continuous on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: He asks to show it's not continuous at every point in $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: @DanZimm Ahhh, now I understand what you mean. I thought that OP had to prove "it is not true that $f$ is continuous at every point", while you understood (probably correctly) "at every point $x\in\mathbb R$, it is not true that $f$ is continuous at $x$". The sentence by OP confuzed me...

Comment: All good :D, but I think it probably `confoooozed' you... ;P